# Database view in IntelliJ IDEA does not show all databases of connection

Tags: mysql, database, intellij-idea, schema

I have added connection to localhost MySQL/MariaDB database in IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.5.

However the Database view tab is showing only one of my databases. How do I get IntelliJ to show the other databases as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right-click on connection -> Properties -> Schemas and Tables tab -> select all the checkboxes in available databases tab -> click OK

Answer (score 2):

In order to show all databases of the connection:

1. Click on the `number` near the connection name (`localhost` in this example).
2. In the popup, select `All schemas`.
3. You should have all the table visible now.

[image]